# Trying to set up new data_directory on Postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Ubuntu 14.04, recently installed Postgres 9.3.

Trying to set up a new data_directory to an attached, larger hard drive (/data), and I changed the postgresql.conf file to reflect that.

However, I get this error when trying to restart the server:

```
user@server:/etc/postgresql/9.3/main$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                     
 * Error: pid file is invalid, please manually kill the stale server process.
```

I don't have too much experience setting up Postgres, so I'm not sure what to do from here, and Googling around provides no quick answer.

Comment: Did you stop PostgreSQL before you moved the data directory? If not, I strongly suggest a `sudo pkill -u postgres`. **Never do anything to the data directory while PostgreSQL is running**.

Comment: I did not, but I have edited the question with new issues.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to change the meaning, it'll confuse people who come here trying to learn about the same issue later. When you have a follow-up or related question please post a new one and link back to this one for context.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu and Debian use `pg_wrapper` to manage PostgreSQL. It's in the `postgresql-common` package.

(As a result, this answer doesn't apply to RHEL/CentOS/Fedora).

If there's no data of value, you can just use `pg_dropcluster` (part of `pg_wrapper`) to drop (delete) your old datadir. This will destroy all data in it. Then use `pg_createcluster` to make a new one in `/data`. That's simplest, but of course it's destructive.

If you want to retain the data, you must:

- Ensure that the file system on the new storage is compatible with PostgreSQL. *Do not attempt to put PostgreSQL on FAT32 / vfat*. I wouldn't attempt to use NTFS on Linux either.
- Create every directory up to the location you want for the new datadir.
- Ensure that the `postgres` user has at least `x` rights on all directories from the data dir down to the `/` directory, especially including the mount point. You may want to `chmod a+x` each directory along the path, or `chgrp postgres` and `chmod g+x` it.
- **stop PostgreSQL**
- `mv` the data directory, as shown by `pg_lsclusters`, to the desired new location. If you copy it instead, use `cp -aRv` to make sure permissions are preserved correctly. Don't just move all contents, move the directory its self.
- Edit `/etc/postgresql/mypgversion/postgresql.conf` and change `data_directory` to point to the new data directory location.
- Start PostgreSQL

I think the mistake you made was, in bold above, that you failed to stop PostgreSQL before moving the datadir. It won't stop the server because it isn't sure it'd be killing the right process, so it refuses to act. You must:

```
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

then make sure that all PostgreSQL processes have exited (*very* important) by making sure that this returns no results:

```
ps -u postgres
```

and only then attempt to start the server again.

**Never** delete `postmaster.pid`.

Comment: But he only wants to *move* the data directory not completely delete everything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep, and `pg_wrapper` should really have a `pg_movecluster`. But it doesn't. You can move it by hand by twiddling the `pg_wrapper` metadata, but it's annoying, and if there's nothing interesting in the existing cluster...

Comment: So just moving the directory and adjusting postgresql.conf does not work on Ubuntu? Seems like a strange way to install it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, in a quick test, it does. `pg_lsclusters` etc parses `postgresql.conf` and because `pg_wrapper` pulls `postgresql.conf` out of the datadir and puts it in `/etc` it's possible to do just what you describe. Please post that as an answer (with appropriate info about permissions, stopping the server first, etc).

Comment: As I don't have any experience with Ubuntu I don't think my answer would be detailed enough. Feel free to add that to yours.

Comment: Added an edit above.

Comment: Alright, I'm in an odd situation where my best solution would be to put the cluster in a NTFS drive. Well, it's not only not advisable but it doesn't even work. Because of the way Linux deals with NTFS partitions, they have no real permission system, and thus Postgres refuses to start: it **mandates** the data dir to be `0700`.

Comment: @igorsantos07 Unsure what this comment has to do with anything here. If you're looking for help post a new quesiton.

Comment: just re-read your answer ;) you mention "I wouldn't attempt to use NTFS on Linux either". I'm adding on top of it: it's not only a suggestion, in fact it won't work even if you try to force that.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to do this is to have your PGDATA (`/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`) symlink-ed to `/data`. Doing it this way no need to change `postgresql.conf`.